# Creating custom alerting policies using data streamed to the cloud from a sensor

Tags: monitoring, google-cloud-platform, google-stackdriver, alerting

I was looking for information and help on how to use data acquired from a sensor device and uploaded to my google cloud project as a metric for an alerting policy on Stackdriver Monitoring.

Currently my team and I are using BigQuery to query the data from the sensor device if that helps.

The main goal I have in mind is to monitor the data coming in from our device and if a certain value or set of values remains too high for an arbitrary Stackdriver Monitoring will send out an incident alert to registered phones and emails.

Admittedly I am rather new to GCP and Stackdriver so try to keep responses in layman's terms.

Answer (score 0):

You should first configure the [notification option](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/support/notification-options) intended, later on when creating the policy you can use the "Notifications (optional)" option.

Related with the [metrics](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/monitoring#metrics) for the creation of this policy, BigQuery don't have support for that kind of process but I found this answer over Stackoverflow about "[How can I trigger an email or other notification based on a BigQuery query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26498876/how-can-i-trigger-an-email-or-other-notification-based-on-a-bigquery-query)" so you could perform a query to check over the changes in your data and alert based on that.